# how to make web browser to allow access only 1 page, that is for gui applications made with html, like how the auto-py-to-exe python module do

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, google-chrome

Comment #"I have an application that embedding the content from another server via iframe. how to prevent the iframe content accessed directly over browser?"#

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.